# Why DefaultMask() method has a receiver of type of IP in Golang?

Tags: go

I was looking into Golang source code [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f4ca598c9f08a4d00942a1c6a6b8cc7d8f162b66/src/net/ip.go#L246) and DefaultMask() under the net package, what I don't understand is why this function is not a package function (without receiver) so from my perpective, proper call would be like:

```
    ip := net.ParseIP("192.168.1.1")
    i := ip.Mask(net.DefaultMask()) // <----
```

instead of the :

```
    ip := net.ParseIP("192.168.1.1")
    i := ip.Mask(ip.DefaultMask()) <----
```

Comment: `net.DefaultMask()` you need to know the IP address in order to know the default mask for it.  You can see so in the implementation you provided.

Answer (score 6):

The IPv4 ***default mask*** has to do with [classful IPv4 assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network#Classful_addressing_definition) - a historical thing mostly.

Class A IPs went from 0.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255, Class B to 191.255.255.255, and Class C to 223.255.255.255. Hence the class mask could be determined simply by looking at the first segment of the IP address. This is why `DefaultMask()` takes an IP address.

For example the IP 192.168.1.1 is a Class C, hence it's default subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

The class mask is irrelevant on the Internet as it uses [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) exclusively (and IPv6).

Comment: make total sense!

Answer (score 2):

You can see why if you look at the source. It needs to know the class:

```
switch {
    case ip[0] < 0x80:
        return classAMask
    case ip[0] < 0xC0:
        return classBMask
    default:
        return classCMask
    }
```